# How to correct misaligned sunglasses temples?

Tags: eyeglasses

Just bought cheap sunglasses abroad but back home I realize temples aren't aligned. I'm scared of breaking them if I try to bend one of the temples. Any suggestion?

[image: Sunglasses with misaligned arms]
[image: Sunglasses with misaligned arms]
[image: Sunglasses with misaligned arms]
[image: Sunglasses with misaligned arms]
[image: Sunglasses with misaligned arms]

Answer (score 3):

When I was a kid my stepfather (blind as a bat and very particular about his glasses frames) would gently heat them by holding over the stove, then gently bend them into desired shape. It was always very effective.

Answer (score 3):

You can mimic the method they use at eye glasses stores buy using a hair blower/dryer.

Use the Dryer on LOW heat, and take your time, slowly bending it into your preferred shape.

The key to this is to do it very slowly to prevent breaking them (cheap or expensive, they run the risk of breaking when you mold them if you don't take your time, so take your time please)

Comment: Thanks! But what is to be bent, the "joints" or the rigid parts? Also there are metallic and plastic parts, I guess only the plastic ones can be bent right?

Answer (score 1):

If they're metal you can just bend them. I've been wearing glasses and cheap sunglasses for about 30 years and never broken a pair doing this. Just make sure you hold the part you're bending separate from the part holding the lenses. I've never had a lens pop out but you want to be careful anyway.

Next time try them on and bend them in the store. Or ask an employee to do it. If you go into a glasses store that's what they'll do anyway.

Comment: Sorted of worked but by bending the joints (where the screw is), which are now technically slightly damaged. Impossible to bend the metal itself because of the vertical thickness (see pictures). Are you talking about bending joints or the long, right parts?

Comment: The joints but not at the screws. Your joint is very close to the screw though so you might want to use needle nose pliers.

Answer (score 0):

Many plastic frames will bend easily when having been in hot water for cleaning.
It should not be boiling hot, just hot enough that you can get your hands in but are not comfy to leave it in for long. (50 C will do.)
If your frame is metal but partly covered in plastic you can use this method for the covered parts.

When you look at your set of glasses, check the bend is not on the bridge between the glasses. If it is, you need to bend the glasses themselves into the right position. It is possible but you will have to be extra careful as there is only a small area and often the bridge is a tender connection.

Better to adjust the legs if that will do the trick.